# Labels disappear behind GIF after animating

Tags: delphi, vcl

All the labels in my project disappear behind the background (a GIF), but none of the buttons or memos. How can I stop this from happening? One of the labels is updated every second, and it appears for a split second after updating, then disappears again.

Here is the form's code:

```
  Object Form2: TForm2 
    Left = 0 
    Top = 0 
    Caption = 'Form2' 
    ClientHeight = 470 
    ClientWidth = 628 
    Color = clBtnFace 
    Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET 
    Font.Color = clWindowText 
    Font.Height = -12 
    Font.Name = 'Segoe UI' 
    Font.Style = [] 
    OnCreate = FormCreate 
    TextHeight = 15 
    
    object Image1: TImage 
      Left = 0 
      Top = 8 
      Width = 625 
      Height = 426
```

And a [link to the gif](https://www.deviantart.com/kirokaze/art/Factory-5-567135270).

This is what I'm using to animate:

```pascal
(imgBackground2.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).Animate := True;
```

I tried to make the form double-buffered and change the order of the components, but they still disappear.

Comment: Did you check the zorder of your controls to make sure the labels are on top of the TImage?

Comment: Yeah, even tried to use "stay on top" but they still disappear behind the GIF

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? And can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Using Delphi 11.4. A minimal reproducible example wouldn't be of much help as there is no code in the entire project except for the GIF animation code. (imgBackground2.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).Animate := True;

Comment: A [mcve] in this case would be to show the contents of your Form's DFM and provide an example GIF.

Comment: Here is the link to the GIF, and the code from the DFM.[link](https://www.deviantart.com/kirokaze/art/Factory-5-567135270) Code: object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 470
  ClientWidth = 628
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -12
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  TextHeight = 15
  object Image1: TImage
    Left = 0
    Top = 8
    Width = 625
    Height = 426

Comment: I was able to reproduce. Both `TLAbel` and `GifViewer` are `TGraphicControl`s, but since the `TGifViewer` updates itself constantly, it becomes the most foreground control of the two. Replace the `TLabel` with a `TStaticText`, which is a `TWinControl` and it will stay in front of the gif.

Comment: Thank you! It works now. Unfortunately, I can't make it any colour other than black without losing the transparency, but that isn't as big of a deal.

Comment: Redrawing a `TImage` *SHOULD NOT* bring it into the foreground. The VCL *SHOULD* be respecting the z-order of overlapping `TGraphicControl`s. If it is not, then that is a bug. In any case, I CANNOT reproduce this in Delphi 12. I put multiple `TLabel`s on top of the `TImage` and they all stay visible while the GIF is animating, as expected.

Comment: @Remy You are right about the label should stay in front, I did not express myself accurately. I tested with 11.3 and here the label doesn't stay in front. Good that it has been fixed in current version.